# Django Image file upload default to random images

Tags: python, django, django-models

My use-case wants that if a user does not upload an Image I choose an image randomly from a pool of images created by the administrator.

That pool of images contain the ones uploaded by admin using django-admin.

I tried some ways like renaming the files and uploaded by the admin ; and randomly select from those name. But those name were to be hardcoded.. So its not a scalable idea.

Any suggestions on how it can be done.

I would prefer if not to use a custom app for it.

Comment: Why not to list all image files in the image admin directory (os.listdir()) then choose one of them then copy a choosed file?

Answer (score 0):

The idea.

```
import os
import os.path
from random import choice
from shutil import copy_file

...
filename_list = os.listdir( ADMIN_DIR )
filename_to_copy = choice( filename_list )
file_to_copy = os.path.join( ADMIN_DIR, filename_to_copy ) # it contains a file to copy
# 'change_filename' is a function that changes a file name for a result file. You should implement it.
new_file = os.path.join( DEST_DIR, change_filename( filename_to_copy ) )
# then copy this file to a destination dir.
copyfile( file_to_copy, new_file )
```